# What should I do, if I need to notice a user about a problem that he can surely help to resolve?

Tags: discussion

I am a user, in fact a great follower of `magentostackexchange` and magento section of `statckoverflow`. Some times when I see some questions, I love to know what would be it's answer. Suppose that I know a user who can answer that question or surely help to solve that question. Rather it may be a question which he may love to answer. In that case how can I notice him about that question ?

I asked this because, I mentioned a question to @marius  once as a comment of one of his recent answers. But that would be strange move if I continue that method. That is because the question he answered would not have any relation with the question that I have mentioned. Hence it would be unfair I mentioned such comment in that context.

So what should I do if such situation arises again. I hope you understand my question. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't answer in the comments of another question as it could be off-topic. I don't think many of the avid users here would mind being pinged on Twitter or social media. Most of them are active there.

The only problem I can see is getting tweets constantly to look at a particular question when I'm here multiple times a day every day answering already - I've probably seen all of the questions ever asked here to be honest.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth.